# Next.js - Stack Driver error reporting - errors are not logged

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stackdriver

I tried to log errors from Next.js app into Stack Driver.

With this library: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/stackdriver-errors-js

App.tsx

```
useEffect(() => {
   TagManager.initialize({
     gtmId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GTM_ID as string,
   })

   if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
     const errorHandler = new StackdriverErrorReporter()
     errorHandler.start({
       key: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY || '',
       projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID || '',
       service: 'service_id',
       version: '2',
     })

     window.onerror = function (_msg, _file, _line, _col, error) {
       // callback is called with an Array[StackFrame]
       if (error) {
         errorHandler.report(error)
       }
     }
  }
}, [])
```

But no errors are logged in stack-driver. Has anyone faced this issue before?
I'll post there my next journey in this situation.

Thanks!

Comment: Which Google Cloud service are you running this code on? Does the service have an IAM role and correct scopes if running on Compute Engine? Edit your question with more details.

Comment: My app is running on vercel.com. I want to use only stackdriver platform. I found https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/error-handling#handling-client-errors. I will let you know about the progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this by using custom ErrorBoundary and wrapped whole `_app.tsx`:

//cc @John Handley

```
import React, { Component, ErrorInfo, ReactNode } from 'react'
import StackdriverErrorReporter from 'stackdriver-errors-js'

interface Props {
  children?: ReactNode
}

interface State {
  hasError: boolean
}

class AppErrorBoundary extends Component<Props, State> {
  public state: State = {
    hasError: false,
  }

  public static getDerivedStateFromError(_: Error): State {
    // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
    return { hasError: true }
  }

  public componentDidCatch(error: Error, errorInfo: ErrorInfo) {
    const errorHandler = new StackdriverErrorReporter()
    errorHandler.start({
      key: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY || '',
      projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID || '',
      service: '',
      version: '2',
    })

    errorHandler.report(error)
    console.error('Uncaught error:', error, errorInfo)
  }

  public render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return <h1>Sorry.. there was an error</h1>
    }

    return this.props.children
  }
}

export default AppErrorBoundary
```